# How to showcase design layouts in portfolio website?

Tags: page-layout

I'm making my portfolio site and I need to showcase my design layouts (magazines, advertisements, newspapers) and would like to know how can I do this to look professional? Do I need to search for some kind of PSD mockups and put them there? Do I need to upload those layout PDF files for perfect quality? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do (if you don't have the option to photograph it in a studio) is to simulate as if it was photographed.

By adding a nice background, lightning effects, 
shadows and grain you can create something nice for in your portfolio.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Take a beautiful **picture of the final print**. Nothing conveys the final result as much as the final result does. And the same goes for business cards in my opinion. All those renderings are nice and all, but they take away from your work (unless rendering is also part of your portfolio).

Answer (score 0):

Use google.

Try:

"editorial design portfolio"

"inspiring editorial design"

"great editorial design"

and derivatives of...

Take from what you see that conveys layouts as you need.